Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' (ts, tsx)
I am creating a Laravel project using Typescript React, and I start creating a tsx file like this
App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home/home';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hello world</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

then I run npm run dev, and it works.
But I want to create a home page like this
Home.tsx
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
    return ( 
       //home page content
    );
}
export default Home;

App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home/home';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/home" Component={Home} />
    </Router>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

then I run npm run dev again, it errors "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'"
resources
\--ts
\----components
\------home
\--------home.tsx
\----app.tsx
tsconfig.json
webpack.mix.js

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}

webpack.mix.js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/ts/app.tsx', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]).react();


Please, help me. I'm new to this

When you run npm run dev it will look at your package.json file to see what the dev script is and you can work from there. What does your package.json file look like?
